# TSQL query optimization on denormalization

Tags: c#, database

I have two tables: `boughtItems(buyerId,ItemId)` and `denormalized(buyerId,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5)`
Let's assume that in `boughtItems` table each buyer has no more than five items. So I am trying to insert data from first table into second. I am doing like this, selecting all rows from first table for each buyer as

```
SELECT itemId FROM boughtItems where buyerId=1
```

and then when all rows are read, I executing corresponding insert command for second table. Is there any way to speed up this process? If needed, I can post my program code as well.

Comment: Please specify which sql -- sql server, oracle, mysql or other

Comment: Do you actually **need** denormalization? Have you performed measurements on realistic amounts of data? Assuming you did and there really is a performance problem, have you tried [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the `boughtItems` table on `buyerId` (so relevant items are stored physically close together, minimizing I/O when querying for items bought by the given buyer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB, you can do this with just one CTE but I think this made it clear.  Remember, I did not test on the server so there may be bugs or typos.

```
WITH ranked AS
(
    SELECT buyerID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY buyerID) AS ItemRank
    FROM boughtItems
), allColumns AS
(
   SELECT buyerID, i1.ItemID as item1, i2.ItemID as item2, i3.ItemID as item3, i4.ItemID as item4, i5.ItemID as item5
   FROM ranked r
   LEFT JOIN boughtItems item1 ON r.buyerID = item1.buyerID and ItemRank = 1
   LEFT JOIN boughtItems item2 ON r.buyerID = item2.buyerID and ItemRank = 2
   LEFT JOIN boughtItems item3 ON r.buyerID = item3.buyerID and ItemRank = 3
   LEFT JOIN boughtItems item4 ON r.buyerID = item4.buyerID and ItemRank = 4
   LEFT JOIN boughtItems item5 ON r.buyerID = item5.buyerID and ItemRank = 5
)
INSERT INTO denormalized (buyerid, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
  SELECT buyerid, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5
  FROM allColumns
```

Comment: It won't do it in the intended way.

Comment: Let say the my query returned set of rows `1,2,3,4,5` will your query insert value 1 into item1 column, value 2 into item2 column and so on

Comment: @Hogan I think he's trying to denormalize his data, assuming by the names of the tables. I've seen it done for quicker data access.

Comment: It does not work as this query inserts all the items in item1 column

Comment: I don't think you're understanding. The first table would look like buyer 1 has bought item 1, buyer 1 has bought item 2. Table 2 would look like buyer 1 bought table,chair (in a single row).

Comment: @Hogan Yes, it may contain from one to five as I wrote in my post

Comment: The ranking function "ROW_NUMBER" must have an ORDER BY clause. Among other issues, but I had the same general idea with a single CTE.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich - Not according to the syntax diagram at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: I ran it on SQL 2008 R2. Not sure if I screwed something up.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Interesting how faster this approach is in compare to my previous.